# Most efficient endless loop in C# (carousel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, carousel, infinite-carousel

Assuming a list of objects, each with an ID, what's the most efficient way of building a carousel, so that each object knows what its previous and next item is. The Last Item's previousId will link to the first item. The first item's previousId will link to the last.

I need the ID of the previous and the ID of the next, as this will be used to populate next and previous buttons on a web page.

I know I could iterate over them, adding placeholders for _next and _prev id, but what's the most **efficient** way to do this?

I figure my object should look like this:

```
class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Next { get; set; }
    public int Prev { get; set; }
}
```

SO, if I have a `List<Item> items` how can I *most efficiently* add the previous and next IDs to each item?

```
    int _prev = items.LastOrDefault().id;
    int _next = items.Count > 1 ? items[1].id : _prev;
    foreach (var i in items) {
        i.prev = _prev;
        i.next = (_next < 
        _prev = i.id;
        //_next = ???
    }
```

I think I'm looking at this wrong way. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why not just an indexer into a list or array? Just add/subtract one and check the bounds...?

Comment: I'm with @Marc Gravell if you used a List or OrderedList with the items in your order all you need to handle is making the list behave circularly. This is by far the most efficient IMO.

Comment: Despite getting the point, *most efficient endless loop* still makes me chuckle.

Comment: Here's another vote for @Marc Gravell.

Comment: @Marc. But, what if the IDs aren't sequential?

Comment: Atomix what have ids got to do with a circular list? You just populate a list on the order you want it, like you do with next/prev. No ids involved. Then just look at list[i+1], but allowing for wrap around. You could even write a custom indexer that takes the positive modulus, so i+/-1 always works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use LinkedList and willing to use indexes instead of foreach as Marc Gravel suggested:

```
int count = items.Length;
for(int index = 0; index < count; index ++)
{
  item.Next = items[(index + 1) % count];
  item.Prev = items[(index - 1 + count) % count];
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this (more or less) for simplicity's sake, but I'm definitely looking into LinkedLists.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) to hold your objects.

Comment: Why not use `LinkedList<T>` which is included in the framework?

Comment: If I knew of it's existence, I wouldn't have mentioned it's implementation. Answer updated =]

Comment: I'll look into this. But am I able to link the end to the beginning with this structure?

Comment: @Atømix: There's no real need to link from the end to the beginning (or from the beginning to the end).  The list knows where its `First` and `Last` nodes are, so in your code you can say that if `CurrentNode == MyList.Last`, then the "next" node is `MyList.First`.

Comment: Cool, thanks Jim/deadlock. I ended up using Alexei's (more or less) for simplicity's sake, but I'm definitely looking into LinkedLists.